# Laravel 4 Mail Connection could not be established with host smtp.gmail.org

Tags: email, laravel, smtp, gmail

I always getting an error when sending an email. I already openned the open_ssl on php.ini . Currently i am using "guzzlehttp/guzzle": "~4.0" for the mail.
Here's my mail.php settings :

```
'driver' => 'smtp',
'host' => 'smtp.gmail.org',
'port' => 587,
'from' => array('address' => 'tokotonight456@gmail.com', 'name' => 'tonight'),
'encryption' => 'tls',
'username' => '', //i already set the username + pass correctly
'password' => '',
'sendmail' => '/usr/sbin/sendmail -bs',
'pretend' => false,

Mail::send('mail', array('firstname'=>'budi'), function($message) {
    $message->to('tokotonight456@gmail.com','lukas aa')->subject('Welcome to the Laravel 4 Auth App!');
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Mandrill driver instead of smtp. Laravel ships with it.

in app/config/mail.php

change this line

```
'driver' => 'mandrill',
```

go to https://mandrillapp.com/settings

sign up and create an an api key

create an app/config/services.php configuration fileand add below configurations and mandrill api key

```
return array(

'mailgun' => array(
    'domain' => '',
    'secret' => '',
),

'mandrill' => array(
    'secret' => 'enter your mandrill api key here',
),

'stripe' => array(
    'model'  => 'User',
    'secret' => '',
),

);
```